# Converting vector<string> to char** results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am a absolutely begginer in C++ but i have an assignent. I have to convert a vector to char** to use it in execvp. So i wrote this test which is building ok but when i run it i get segmentation fault instead of "First". I am bad at pointer and i would like your help. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string>* list = new vector<string>();
    list->push_back("First");
    list->push_back("Second");
    list->push_back("Third");

    char ** arr;
    arr[0] = strdup(list->at(0).c_str());

    cout << arr[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Ok here's the actual problem. The Command::getCommandArray() seems to work as expected but when i call it from main and try to display the arr[0] it results in segmentation fault again. Why?

```
// Command.cpp
char** Command::getCommandArray()
{
    int i=0;
    int len = args->size() + 2;
    char* arr[len];

    arr[0] = strdup(this->commandName->c_str());
    arr[len-1] = NULL;

    for (i=0; i<this->args->size(); i++)
    {
        arr[i+1] = strdup(this->args->at(i).c_str());
    }

    cout << "in: " << arr[0] << endl; // PRINTS AS EXPECTED

    return arr;
}

// main.cpp
do {
    char** arr = tmp->getCommandArray();
    cout << arr[0] << endl; // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE
} while((tmp = tmp->getPipeline()) != NULL);
```

**EDIT 2 Ok i solved it. Thank you very much!**

I had to change line

```
char* arr[len];
```

to

```
char** arr = new char*[len];
```

Comment: `char** arr` is a pointer to some memory. What memory does it point to?

Comment: You haven't initialized `arr`. Accessing it is undefined behavior. Something like `const char* arr[3];` would be preferable though.

Comment: so, how am i supposed to initialize it? if i dont know the length of vector?

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason to duplicate strings here, or to manually manage memory. You can just use another vector to store the char pointers, and get a pointer to that vector's memory.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> list;
    list.push_back("First");
    list.push_back("Second");
    list.push_back("Third");

    std::vector<char*> ptr_list;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != list.size(); ++i) {
        ptr_list.push_back(&list.at(i)[0]);
    }

    char** arr = &ptr_list[0];

    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> list;
    list.push_back("First");
    list.push_back("Second");
    list.push_back("Third");

    char** arr = new char*[list.size()];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != list.size(); ++i) {
        arr[i] = strdup(list.at(i).c_str());
    }
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != list.size(); ++i) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the argv and envp arrays you pass in to `execve()` need to be null terminated (in addition to the strings in those arrays):

```
char ** convert(std::vector<std::string> v)
{
    char ** t = new char* [v.size() + 1];

    // Need this for execve
    t[v.size()] = nullptr;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        t[i] = strdup(v[i].c_str());
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: dangerous: an entirely internally allocated data structure returned as a pointer. Who and when to take care of the deletion?

Comment: If the result of convert() is being used immediately by execve(2) without an intervening fork(2), then there is no need (or even opportunity) to delete. If I were doing this with an intervening fork(2), I'd wrap this in something that would go through and free() everything allocated by strdup() in its destructor as well as the array of pointers itself.